# Edit and continue not works in very simple one line method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I have very simple class method. Here it is:

```
  public string SendDataInHandle(string handleName, string data)
  {
      return _connectionType.SendDataInHandle(handleName, data);
  }
```

I put a breakpoint on this line and trying to add console.writeline like this

```
  public string SendDataInHandle(string handleName, string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("123");
        return _connectionType.SendDataInHandle(handleName, data);
    }
```

And got an error:

Error   1   Modifying a 'method' which contains a dynamic invocation will prevent the debug session from continuing while Edit and Continue is enabled. ***.cs  248 9   ***

What am i doing wrong ? Where is dynamic invocation ? How to fix it ?

.net 4.5 simple console application with target platform x86

Answer (score 0):

It's possible from this msdn that you "modified" the current executing line by inserting the Console.WriteLine.

Check out the first bullet here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx

"Changes to the current statement or any other active statement.

Active statements include any statements, in functions on the call stack, that were called to get to the current statement."

Comment: tried to put it after current executing line - same effect, even in other method - same error